# Is there a way to disable portrait-upside down orientation but enable regular portrait and landscape orientations?

Tags: android, android-orientation

I need to prevent the upside-down portrait orientation in my app, but still allow all three of the other orientations to be triggered by physically rotating the device.

I'm calling `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED)` (which I understand to be the default) in `onCreate()` of my activities.  The reason I am calling this is because some of my screens need to be specifically set to portrait and/or landscape, but most screens by default use the sensor.

This seems to result in my desired behaviour on some devices (Nexus 6, Samsung Galaxy S4), but the Nexus 7 displays portrait upside down mode when the device is held upside down.  For unrelated reasons I can't allow this.

Is there a way to disable portrait upside-down on all devices but still allow the other 3 modes?

Comment: sorry  i not understood rightly! - u want to setActivityOrientation in same activity not all!? - why not declare ActivityOrientation in manifest? - in this form : android:screenOrientation="portrait" - sorry but my english not good maybe not understood you question correctly!

Comment: The same problem happens whether I use the manifest or declare the orientation in java.  Basically what I would like to do is OR the two possible orientations, something like `android:screenOrientation="portrait|sensorLandscape"` but this doesn't seem to be supported.

Comment: this happened in all device or some device? - i think u said in `Nexus 7` right? - u test your app in real device or via AVD(genymotion and ...)?

Comment: All 3 test devices are physical devices.

Answer (score 0):

Unspecified let's the implementation decide what it wants to do. On the Neus 7, this is apparantly to allow everything, like `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR`.

You could circumvent this by specifying the slightly less "Do whatever you want" option, being `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR`.

Comment: `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR` appears to behave the same way as `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR` on the Nexus 7.  I'm not sure what the difference is between the two - the docs are not clear on this.

Comment: According to the docs, "Orientation is determined by a physical orientation sensor: the display will rotate based on how the user moves the device. This allows any of the 4 possible rotations, regardless of what the device will normally do (for example some devices won't normally use 180 degree rotation)." Seeing as they put it there explicitly, I assumed it meant that. Perhaps the Nexus 7 does something new that is not properly documented.